# How to pass input file parameter from html page to a Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I created a webserver using Python Flask. My "index.html" loads a table. I am planning to create a new field "view result" to each row of the table. On clicking view result, I should be able to visualize the data. I want the filename (corresponding to each entry of "view result"), to be the input file parameter to a javascript.

[image: Table as viewed in index.html]

The filename should get passed here `d3.csv("/static/<filename>.csv", function(data){...}` which belongs to a file named `view_data.js` and data from corresponding file is visualized in another html page.

I have `index.html` page and `view_data.js` ready. How do I pass filename from `index.html` page to `data.js` for visualization?

For now I have hardcoded the filename in `view_data.js`.

Answer (score 1):

Are you familiar with element selectors and events in javascript?

A simple implementation would be to set up event triggers that will fire when clicking each link, using the filename as that you store in a data attribute.

```
<a class="view-trigger" data-filename="filename_1.csv">view result</a>
<a class="view-trigger" data-filename="filename_2.csv">view result</a>
```

etc

You can set up the event using something like a specific class on each of the links (in the example `view-trigger`.

```
var resultLinks = document.getElementsByClassName(".view-trigger")

for(var i = 0; i < resultLinks.length; i++) {
  (function(index) {
    resultLinks[index].addEventListener("click", function(event) {  
       var filename = event.target.getAttribute('data-filename');
       d3.csv("/static/" + filename + ".csv", function(data){...}        
     })
   })(i);
}
```

I haven't tested this code so you may need to fix/adjust for your case. If you are not familiar with these concepts it's worth reading a bit more about them.

Also, `d3.js` also seems to come with utilities to do [DOM selection](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#select) and [handling events](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#handling-events), so you may want to use those instead.